# pan_tilt_port: No motors found + Dynamixel MX-64AR

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have attached a dynamixel motor MX-64AR via USB to my laptop. The distro of my ROS is indigo running of Ubuntu 14.04. I looked into other answers, but I couldn't solve my problem. When I run the following launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="dynamixel_manager" pkg="dynamixel_controllers" type="controller_manager.py" required="true" output="screen">
        <rosparam>
            namespace: dxl_manager
            serial_ports:
                pan_tilt_port:
                    port_name: "/dev/ttyUSB0"
                    baud_rate: 8000
                    min_motor_id: 1
                    max_motor_id: 4
                    update_rate: 20
        </rosparam>
    </node>
</launch>
```

I get the following output in the terminal:

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dynamixel_manager/namespace: dxl_manager
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/baud_rate: 8000
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/max_motor_id: 4
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/min_motor_id: 1
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/port_name: /dev/ttyUSB0
 * /dynamixel_manager/serial_ports/pan_tilt_port/update_rate: 20
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.19

NODES
  /
    dynamixel_manager (dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4794]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 86c272d8-28ba-11e6-817c-e09467568303
process[dynamixel_manager-2]: started with pid [4813]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:92: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.motor_states_pub = rospy.Publisher('motor_states/%s' % self.port_namespace, MotorStateList)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamixel_driver/dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:93: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.diagnostics_pub = rospy.Publisher('/diagnostics', DiagnosticArray)
[INFO] [WallTime: 1464869228.261456] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 1 through 4...
[FATAL] [WallTime: 1464869228.598303] pan_tilt_port: No motors found.
================================================================================REQUIRED process [dynamixel_manager-2] has died!
process has died [pid 4813, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/dynamixel_controllers/controller_manager.py __name:=dynamixel_manager __log:=/home/mahsa/.ros/log/86c272d8-28ba-11e6-817c-e09467568303/dynamixel_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/mahsa/.ros/log/86c272d8-28ba-11e6-817c-e09467568303/dynamixel_manager-2*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[dynamixel_manager-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Also I did : dmesg | grep tty
and got:

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[  161.384192] usb 1-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Can anyone help me to solve the problem. Do I need to add more information in the launch file?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235929/pan_tilt_port:-no-motors-found-+-dynamixel-mx-64ar/) by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
`8000` is a really strange nr for a baud rate. Are you sure that is correct?

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-06-02**:
@gvdhoorn I looked into [this link](http://support.robotis.com/en/product/dynamixel/mx_series/mx-64at_ar.htm) for setting the baud rate. Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Dynamixel may support a baud rate of `8000`, but that doesn't mean your FTDI converter supports it. That would be something to check. Perhaps see if `9600` works better, but it probably depends on what the Dynamixel is configured for.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MahsaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/22552/mahsap/) on 2016-06-03**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for pointing out baud rate. I checked the manual again. I solved this baud rate issue.

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-09-27**:
I have this problem which cost me many days of effort without getting solution, please check it [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/271596/arbotix_ros-can-not-detect-servos-via-arbotix-m-controller/) what is the buad rate for dynamixel motor AX-12A